# Can the Quartz scheduler be used for simulation?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I'm looking at using the Quartz scheduler, but I need to be able to use it both in 'live' mode, using the real clock, and 'simulation' mode where I control the simulated clock. Is this possible with Quartz? I couldn't see anything in the docs that suggested it was.

Thanks, Jon

Comment: I have a real need for a quartz-like scheduler for a simulation environment (mostly "slow-time", with a clock that can pause/advance slowly, but maybe for "fast-time" in the future as well...)  Did you find anything?  Our custom hacked solution is unsatisfying.

Comment: @Andersoj: No, sorry, we ended up rolling our own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation I don't believe what I'm trying to do is possible. There is a TimeBroker interface in Quartz but the documentation states that it is not currently used. Quartz currently always uses the system clock and there is no way to override.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you need a heart-bit object, which rate you can control, possibly by using system property.

Quartz' [SimpleTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html) has a granularity of 1 ms for repeat interval, so, in theory, it can be used to implement the heart-bit object and cover variety of rates.

Just make sure that your system can cope with arrhythmia ( missing heart bits ).

Comment: When in simulation, I need 'time' to replay as fast as possible, so not sure that would work.